# How to combine data by two-year intervals in R

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in the data frame that categorizes length in two-year intervals by region and I am stumped on how. I included sample data below with years 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, and 2019.

I want to:

1. Find the first year in each region.
2. Set the year as a starting point for two-year intervals in each region.
3. If the region has data available for both years in the interval, label the two-year interval as "year1 - year2" in the new column.
4. If not, leave the year as is in the new column.

I think step 1 could use `min` and steps 3-4 could use `if_else` but I am not sure how to execute step 2.

Thank you!

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=500, ncol=0))

set.seed(1)

df$region <- sample(c("North", "Central", "South"),
                       size = nrow(df), 
                       replace = TRUE)

df$year <- sample(c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2019"),
                    size = nrow(df), 
                    replace = TRUE)

df$length <- sample(1:100, size = nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make year numeric.

Get the minimum year for each region (which happens to be 2010 for all)

Get the total length for each region by year (figured this was what you wanted to do, but avoid the sum if necessary).

Join the start year data frame (for cases when start =/= 2010 for all)

Group by region again, check what the next value will be for each year with lead(), and whether this value is the year that follows the current year, thus creating an interval.

If the next row is the following year, add this year's length to next year's, if it's not, keep the length of the current year as the value.

Paste the intervals together

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(year = as.numeric(year))%>%
  tibble()

start_year <- df %>%
  group_by(region)%>%
  summarise(start = min(year))

data <-  df %>%
  arrange(year)%>%
  group_by(region, year)%>%
  summarise(length = sum(length), .groups = "drop")%>%
  left_join(start_year, by = "region") %>%
  group_by(region)%>%
  mutate(next_year = lead(year, 1))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(successive_years = lead(year, 1)- year == 1,
         two_year_total = case_when(successive_years ~ length + lead(length, 1),
                                    !successive_years ~ length),
         interval = case_when(successive_years ~ paste0(year, "-", lead(year,1)),
                              !successive_years ~ paste(year)),
         interval_length = case_when(successive_years == TRUE ~ two_year_total,
                                     !successive_years  ~ length)) %>%
  select(region, interval, interval_length)
```

Think that's roughly what you need? Could could be worked on to be more efficient for sure.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! Here, I do not want to sum the lengths. Instead, I want to be able to cluster (or group) length by two-year intervals for when I want to conduct a distribution-related analysis (ie. Kolmogorov-Smirnov) on length. How would you modify the code to cluster them by intervals instead of sum? And, your sample code creates intervals that overlap (I.e., 2010-2011 and 2011-2012). I want them not to overlap (ie., 2010-2011 and 2012-2013).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, RE: your comment. That's a bit trickier, but applying a similar methodology (and maybe it'd have been better to go back and use purrr:: the whole way through, but sunk costs and all that).
The key steps really, are storing the lengths as lists, two year periods from start as lists and then similar hammers to before, whilst being a bit tricky with alternating lag and lead in the mutate(interval =...) step.

I expect there's a **much much** better solution given how the game changed. Will look forward to someone posting one :)

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(year = as.numeric(year))%>%
  tibble()

start_year <- df %>%
  group_by(region)%>%
  summarise(start = min(year), two_years = list(seq(start, 2030, 2)))

df <- df %>% 
  arrange(region, year)%>%
  group_by(region, year)%>%
  summarise(length = list(length))%>%
  left_join(start_year, by = "region")%>%
  mutate(successive_years = lead(year, 1) - year == 1,
         start_interval = year %in% two_years[[1]])%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(interval = case_when(start_interval & successive_years ~ paste0(year, "-", lead(year, 1)),
                              !start_interval & lag(successive_years, 1) ~ paste0(lag(year,1), "-", year),
                              start_interval & !successive_years ~ paste(year),
                              is.na(successive_years) ~ paste(year)))

#unnest the list & get rid of unnecessary columns:
df %>%
  group_by(region, interval)%>%
  summarise(length = unlist(length). groups = "drop")%>%
  select(-start, -two_years, -successive_years, -start_interval)
```

Comment: This is it! Thank youuu!